# Is this a valid way to determine which diodes are on in an op-amp based rectifier?

Tags: operational-amplifier, diodes, rectifier, differential-amplifier, precision-rectifier

[image]

Consider the circuit above, where we are treating the diodes as ideal.  Let's take the case where Vs < 0.  Since V- = V+ = 0 for both U8 and U9, that automatically means the current is to the left in both R1's.

I'm wondering if one can then justify using the following non-rigorous reasoning: the source Vs is essentially "pulling" current to the left, i.e. it tends to create voltages that are biased towards the left.  This causes the top D2 to be on, and the bottom D2 to be off.  Furthermore, whenever you have a pair of diodes in a circuit like this, one is on and the other is off.  Therefore, the top D1 is off, and the bottom D1 is on.

As you can see, my reasoning is quite nebulous.  But is there a way to make it more foolproof?  All I know is that in principle you would have to apply Kirchoff's laws to the various nodes and loops of the circuit, but that quickly becomes unwieldy, when all I'm trying to do at this stage is figure out which diodes are conducting.  Isn't there some simpler method which can nevertheless be properly justified using logic?

Comment: The most correct method is to first understand the idea of ​​the circuit and then analyze it step by step through simple equivalent circuits. To do this, in this seemingly complex schematic, simpler circuit building blocks should be seen.

Comment: Why have 2 components with the same name? Please fix this, because no-one answering this question will want to write "top" and "bottom" twice into every sentence.

Comment: Here are some op-amp concepts and subcircuits necessary to understand this op-amp circuit: negative feedback, virtual ground, inverting amplifier, non-inverting amplifier, differential amplifier,  half-wave precision rectifier. You also need to know the most general idea of converting a half-wave rectifier into a full-wave rectifier.